# Include a meta tag to wicket application

Tags: javascript, ajax, wicket

Could you please help me how to add meta tag on header for wicket 1.5 version, generally I use the below code to add js script in the header. I want to run my application in EGDE simulation mode as the wicket-ajax.js performance issue is solved there

```
JQUERY_SCRIPT = newJavaScriptResourceReference(Style.class, "jquery-1.11.0.min.js");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IHeaderResponse#renderString("<meta ...>");`

See https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/wicket-1.5.x/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/IHeaderResponse.java#L300

Or you can just put it in YourPage.html

Comment: I was not able to add it in my html as internal client own frame work run and it over ride the meta tag. I just want to run the application in EDGE form the start.
I would request you to get me code snippet if you have 
Note: I am using wicket 1.3.1 version

Comment: Sorry, Wicket 1.3.1 is older than me.